# Print in bluetooth device-Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, printing, bluetooth

I am developing a cross platform app.

I need print in printer Intermec PR2

I use this codes:

**Class in .Droid**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(clsBluetooth))]
namespace Bluetooth.Droid
{
    public class clsBluetooth : IBluetooth
    {
        private BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
        private BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        private BufferedWriter outReader = null;
        private BluetoothDevice device = null;

        public void Imprimir(string pStrNomBluetooth, int intSleepTime, string pStrTextoImprimir)
        {
            try
            {
                string bt_printer = (from d in adapter.BondedDevices
                                     where d.Name == pStrNomBluetooth
                                     select d).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

                device = adapter.GetRemoteDevice(bt_printer);

                UUID applicationUUID = UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

                socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);

                socket.Connect();

                outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.InputStream));

                outReader.WriteAsync(pStrTextoImprimir);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> PairedDevices()
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> devices = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            foreach (var bd in adapter.BondedDevices)
                devices.Add(bd.Name);

            return devices;
        }
    }
}
```

**Interface in Potable**

```
public interface IBluetooth
{
    ObservableCollection<string> PairedDevices();

    void Imprimir(string pStrNomBluetooth, int intSleepTime, string pStrTextoImprimir);
}
```

**Call of method**

```
DependencyService.Get<IBluetooth>().Imprimir(SelectedBthDevice,200,"HolaMundo");
```

My error happens when I enter the class in the .Droid and it executes the sentence `socket.Connect ();` Does not seem to connect to the device.
Someone could help me to see the script or how the code could change so that the connection to the device works correctly

Comment: Do you get any exceptions or anything when connecting the socket?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Sorry, forget to include the error, this is: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

Comment: But check it, solve all the errors but where should print on the device does not, I try with this code:                                                socket.Connect();
                    
                    outReader = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.InputStream));
                    
                    outReader.Write(pStrTextoImprimir);

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the insecure socket communication like:

```
socket = device.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
```

instead of the existing secure one:

```
socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
```

If you are able to connect after that you can write to printer as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pStrTextoImprimir);
socket.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

For further details [refer to](http://sumiran-lingwal.blogspot.in/2018/01/mobile-xamarin-bluetooth-print-image-on-toshiba.html).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18600716)

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Only complexity is that the full content/code for answering is big. How to deal with it?